# Import Spring-Boot Configuration class (Project A) in ext-spring.xml (Project B)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a project A that use SPRING BOOT and it have this ConfigurationClass for this

```
package it.blabla.common.couponing.configuration;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "it.***", "it.**" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:couponing-${application.environment}.properties")
public class CouponingConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

..
```

I have Spring Project B without Spring-Boot that IMPORT and USE Project A.

How can i import Spring-Boot configuration in project B?

For example, for others project that using spring xml file I use this instruction in ext-spring.xml project B

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/projectA-spring.xml"/>
```

I try import spring Boot Configuration using

```
 <bean class="it.blabla.common.couponing.configuration.CouponingConfiguration "></bean>
```

but receive this error

```
LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext
```

What is the best way for do that? Is possible? Can I use springBoot Project in a non-spring-boot project ?

Comment: `@ComponentScan("it.blabla.common.couponing.configuration")` try this in the Sproject B.

Comment: In project B it doesn't work because there isn't spring-boot then it use xml configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was e dependency version problem

I imported configuration:

```
<bean class="it.blabla.common.couponing.configuration.CouponingDatabaseConfiguration"></bean>
```

and change this versions

```
<spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.data.version>1.10.2.RELEASE</spring.data.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it works and I haven't console errors